# DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA and DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID

Tags: https, ipmi, ssl-certificate-errors

scenario is trying to connect via web browser to the IPMI of a new server I have; from Windows 10 either Internet Explorer 11 or Edge.  Both report **This site is not secure** with the error being *DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA* and *DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID*.

Now with the IPMI it has the option for me to replace the default factory installed certs with a new certficate and private key.

I tried doing (in linux) `openssel req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout newprivatekey.pem -out newpubliccert.pem`

I uploaded that successfully to the IPMI and now I only get one of the above errors (sorry I forget which at moment)

Can someone explain

- what does *DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA* mean?
- what does *DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID* mean?
- what is the correct way is fixing this so they do not show up?
- and even though these errors show up and the browser has a red highlight at the top, HTTPS is still actually working correct?